# 301 status redirect code

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-301

I'm a novice with a wordpress website. I ran it through a seo checker and was told that my site has a 302 code rather than a 200 code, and that this is a critical error.

After googling I found an article instructing me to go to the the .htaccess file.

I opened the file, and found below:

```
Options -Indexes


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)  wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Should I just delete the link with the 301 code or change to 200?

Thanks in advance for any assistance or insight. I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: You're missing an understanding of what the codes mean.  A 200 status is not something you set yourself.  Specifically it means that a request has succeeded. 

301 and 302 are redirect codes.  A 301 redirect means that the page has permanently moved to a new location. A 302 redirect means that the move is only temporary.

A good reference point to understanding the meaning of different codes is https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Thanks for the resource but the redirect is redirecting the page to the same url / home page. why would this have happened? there was not old page and is no new page.

Comment: I don't have an easy answer for you if your homepage is redirecting to itself. It might be plugin related.  You can try turning off your plugins one by one to see if any of those are causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .htaccess *is* corrupted (by a plugin or otherwise) you can try and replace it.  From the looks of your existing file, you're using a WordPress multi-site installation.  You can try replacing the current .htaccess in the subfolder with the following:

WordPress 3.5 and up

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

WordPress 3.0 through 3.4.2

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: All this goodness can be found on the WordPress Codex at https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: Thanks so very much

Comment: You're most welcome.  If the answer was correct, please take a moment to accept it.  Thanks!